# Python OpenGL - How to find the current world coordinate of a point after transformation?

Tags: python, opengl, pyopengl

In C++, I can find the current position of a point like this:

```
glm::vec3 somePoint(x,y,z); //x,y,z are some float values
glm::mat4 translationMatrix = glm::translate(glm::mat4(1.0f), glm::vec3(xTrans, yTrans, zTrans));

glm::vec4 currentPointPosition = translationMatrix*glm::vec4(somePoint,1);
```

How can I do the same calculation in Python to get `curretPointPosition`? Can I use Python's pyrr?

In PyOpenGL, I have the following code:

```
somePoint = [x,y,z]
translationMatrix= pyrr.matrix44.create_from_translation(pyrr.Vector3([xTrans, yTrans, zTrans]))
currentPointPosition = ?
```

Comment: It can be done by converting the (x,y,z,1) point to an NP array and keep translationMatrix as a pyrr. Then dot product like this: currentPointPosition = currentPointPosition.dot(translationMatrix). I prefer @Rabbid76 answer though because I can use GLM for C++ and PyGLM for Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the OpenGL Mathematics (GLM) library for Python ([PyGLM](https://github.com/Zuzu-Typ/PyGLM))

```py
somePoint = glm.vec3(x, y, z)
tranaltionVec = glm.vec3(xTrans, yTrans, zTrans)
translationMatrix = glm.translate(glm.mat4(1), tranaltionVec)
currentPointPosition = translationMatrix * glm.vec4(somePoint, 1)
```

The syntax with the [Pyrr Maths Library](https://pyrr.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#pyrr-maths-library) is slightly different.

```py
somePoint = pyrr.Vector3((x, y, z))
tranaltionVec = pyrr.Vector3((xTrans, yTrans, zTrans))
translationMatrix = pyrr.matrix44.create_from_translation(tranaltionVec)
currentPointPosition = pyrr.Vector4.from_vector3(somePoint, 1) @ translationMatrix
```